# Angularjs functions for searching and updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface

I am working on the UI for a simple todo app, I have the backend developed and am trying to implement the functions for the front end but am kind of struggling. I want to implement a search and update function but I haven't had much luck thus far. Help would be great.

index.js

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.todos = [
    {id:1, text:'Mow the lawn',  selected:false},         
    {id:2, text:'Wash the car',  selected:false}
  ];

  $scope.getTotalTodos = function () {
    return $scope.todos.length;
  };


  $scope.addTask = function () {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.text, id:$scope.id, date_created:Date.now, selected:false});
    $scope.text= '';
    $scope.id= '';
  };

  $scope.removeTask = function () {
    $scope.todos = _.filter($scope.todos, function(todo){
      return !todo.selected;
    });
  };

  $scope.showDetails = function(task_id) {
     var found = $filter('filter')($scope.todos, {id: task_id}, true);
     if (found.length) {
         $scope.selected = JSON.stringify(found[0]);
     } else {
         $scope.selected = 'Not found';
     }
  }


  $scope.updateTask = function (task_id) {
  // search $scope.todos for the item to update
  var indexOfTask;
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.todos.length;i++) {
     if($scope.todos[i].id===$scope.id) 
      indexOfTask = i;
      $scope.todos[i] = todo;
      $scope.todos.push();
      $scope.text= '';
      $scope.id= '';
  }

  // update the todo


};


}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Todo App</title>
    <header>Todo App</header>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">




  </head>

  <body>

    <html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/vast-shadow:n4:all.js"></script>
    <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/vast-shadow:n4:all;megrim.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="todo-wrapper" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <h2>You have <span class="emphasis">{{getTotalTodos()}}</span> tasks</h2>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.selected"/>
          <span class="selected-{{todo.selected}}">{{todo.id}}: {{todo.text}} {{todo.date_created}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form>
        <input class="add-input" placeholder="id" type="text" ng-model="id" ng-model-instant />
        <input class="add-input2" placeholder="task name" type="text" ng-model="text" ng-model-instant />
        <button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTask()"><h2>Add</h2></button>
        <button class="search-btn" ng-click="showDetails(task_id)"><h2>Search</h2></button>
      </form>
        <button class="update-btn" ng-click="updateTask(task)"><h3>Update Task</h3></button>
      <button class="clear-btn" ng-click="removeTask()">Remove Task</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>




  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please illustrate what you are expecting and what you have got. Put it to JSFiddle may help.

Comment: Okay this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/c85gq14k/1/ although it isn't working quite right, I haven't used JSFiddle before.

Comment: for searching you can read about filters in a view. updating view is nothing like setting ng-model since angular is two-way data binding. To update on server side, use PUT, to add new POST.

Comment: The server side works for update and post the ui side should be able to update and that is where I am having the issue.

Comment: The update and search functions do not have to be implemented the way I am trying to I just need a method that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add everything related to a todo directly inside of the `ng-repeat` so it's easier to reference the item in the todos array.

Please have a look at the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/c85gq14k/8/) or the demo below. (I've commented your css to have it easier to debug the app.)

Next you have to implement `ng-resource` or a custom `$http` factory to do the server update.

Your `showDetails` method with the filtering should work too. I've just added it to `ng-repeat` so it's easier to show the filtered result.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('todoCtrl', TodoCtrl);

function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.todos = [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'Mow the lawn',
        selected: false
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Wash the car',
        selected: false
    }];
    $scope.id = $scope.todos.length + 1; //later create an uuid

    $scope.getTotalTodos = function () {
        return $scope.todos.length;
    };


    $scope.addTask = function () {
        $scope.todos.push({
            editMode: false,
            text: $scope.text,
            id: $scope.id,
            date_created: Date.now,
            selected: false
        });
        $scope.text = '';
        $scope.id = '';
    };

    $scope.removeTask = function (todo) {
        /*$scope.todos = _.filter($scope.todos, function (todo) {
            return !todo.selected;
        });*/
        $scope.todos.pop(todo);
        //update server now with ngResource...
    };

    $scope.showDetails = function (task_id) {
        var found = $filter('filter')($scope.todos, {
            id: task_id
        }, true);
        if (found.length) {
            $scope.selected = JSON.stringify(found[0]);
        } else {
            $scope.selected = 'Not found';
        }
    }

    $scope.editTask = function(todo) {
        todo.editMode = true;
        console.log(todo);
    };
    
    $scope.save = function(todo) {
        todo.editMode = false;
        // update data at server now too. $scope.todos is up-to-date
    }
    $scope.updateTask = function (task_id) {
        // search $scope.todos for the item to update
        var indexOfTask;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.todos.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.todos[i].id === $scope.id) indexOfTask = i;
            $scope.todos[i] = todo;
            $scope.todos.push();
            $scope.text = '';
            $scope.id = '';
        }

        // update the todo


    };


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/edit-form.html">
        <div ng-show="todo.editMode">
            <input ng-model="todo.text" />
            <button ng-click="save(todo)">save</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    
    <div class="todo-wrapper" ng-controller="todoCtrl">
         <h2>You have <span class="emphasis">{{getTotalTodos()}}</span> tasks</h2>

        <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="enter search term...." />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: searchText">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.selected" /> <span class="selected-{{todo.selected}}">{{todo.id}}: {{todo.text}} {{todo.date_created}}</span>
                <div ng-include="'partials/edit-form.html'"></div>
                <button class="clear-btn" ng-click="removeTask(todo)">Remove</button>
                <button class="clear-btn" ng-click="editTask(todo)">Edit</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
            <input class="add-input" placeholder="id" type="text" ng-model="id" ng-model-instant />
            <input class="add-input2" placeholder="task name" type="text" ng-model="text" ng-model-instant />
            <button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTask()">
                 <h2>Add</h2>

            </button>
            <!--<button class="search-btn" ng-click="showDetails(task_id)">
                        <h2>Search</h2>
                    </button>-->
        </form>
        <!--<button class="update-btn" ng-click="updateTask(task)">
             <h3>Update Task</h3>

        </button>-->
        
</div>
<!-- <script src="js/index.js"></script>-->
<div>
```

Comment: Okay one last thing on that delete function it just removes the last task it doesn't work if you want to remove the first task how would I approach fixing this?

Comment: OK, I've had a look at the mdn docs and pop is always removing the last index seems there is no option for passing the position. You can fix this with `$scope.todos.splice(todo, 1);`.

Comment: And I would change the function call of remove to `ng-click="removeTask($index)"` because I'm not sure why the other one is working. This is cleaner because splice needs the index of the item to remove or you could add `$scope.todos.indexOf(todo)` to get the index of the item.

Comment: I got it working so I really appreciate all the help.